# Excel VBA: Loop to cut and paste string into new rows

Tags: excel

My goal is outlined below:
1. Loop through rows on a worksheet (column B)
2. If the cell contains more than one email address then extract the email address and paste it into a new row (column B). The data I need to process may contain more than 2 email addresses in a cell. Column A cells will all contain the same data. Essentially, every cell in column B should contain only one email address.
3. Delete all rows with duplicate addresses.
4. Delete all "junk" data (##Receive, Deliver)

In the example picture below the example3 email and the example4 email should be cut/pasted into their own rows and example 5 would remain.
Currently, my code places all the blank rows at the top. I do not have a solution for cutting/pasting the strings into the new blank row. I also do not have a solution for deleting duplicate rows.

```
Sub FormatMessageTrace()

Dim a As Range
Dim b As Range
Dim str As String
Dim openPos As Integer
Dim closePos As Integer
Dim midBit As String

Set a = Selection

On Error Resume Next

For Each b In a.Rows

str = b.Value
openPos = InStr(str, "")
closePos = InStr(str, ";")
midBit = Mid(str, openPos, closePos - openPos + 1)
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
b.Replace midBit, ""

Next

Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns("B").Replace _
What:="##Receive, Deliver", Replacement:="", _
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True

End Sub
```

Example of data:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used:

- VBA arrays so as to speed up the processing
- Regular expression to extract email addresses from your strings.

  - *A regex to extract all valid email addresses is exceedingly complex, so this one has some limitations. For example, the regex provided will not match email addresses using an IP address instead of a domain name*
- A Dictionary to ensure we exclude duplicate emails
- I used late-binding for simplicity and portability. You can convert this to early-binding which will provide the advantage of Intellisense when writing code, as well as perhaps being slightly more efficient.
- The code is annotated, but feel free to ask questions.

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub extEmails()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes() As Variant
    Dim dEmails As Object, RE As Object, MC As Object, M As Object
    Dim V As Variant, I As Long

    'Regex to match emails
    Const sPat As String = "\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}\b"

'Set source and results worksheets and ranges
'Change as you will. I used `sheet2` and column C for the results
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet2")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("sheet2")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 3)

'read source data into array
'assumes data is in Column B
With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
End With

'Initialize regex engine
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = sPat
    .Global = True
    .ignorecase = True
End With

'Initialize dictionary
Set dEmails = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dEmails.comparemode = vbTextCompare

'Create collection of unique email addresses
For Each V In vSrc
    If RE.test(V) = True Then
        Set MC = RE.Execute(V)
        For Each M In MC
            If Not dEmails.exists(M.Value) Then _
                dEmails.Add M.Value, M.Value
        Next M
    End If
Next V

'create results array
ReDim vRes(1 To dEmails.Count, 1 To 1)

'populate results array
I = 0
For Each V In dEmails
    I = I + 1
    vRes(I, 1) = V
Next V

'write results to worksheet
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1), UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly, thank you. Is there an addition to this code that would delete all rows that contain a certain domain name in an email address such as "@whatever.com"?

Comment: Just check the retrieved email address `M` against your list of exclusions in the loop before you add it to the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I find the description of your problem rather confusing but hopefully this function should help you.  Its input is any string, its output is a list of emails contained in the input string.

```
Function RegExEmails(contents As String) As String

    Dim m As Match
    Dim c As MatchCollection
    Dim r As New RegExp

    With r
        .Pattern = "[^\s<(:]+@[^\s<>;,)]+[/\b\w+\b/g]"
        .Global = True
    End With

    Set c = r.Execute(contents)

    For Each m In c
        RegExtract = RegExtract & m.Value & ", "
    Next

    RegExEmails = Left(RegExtract, Len(RegExtract) - 2)
End Function
```

For RegEx to work you will need to add the last two references highlighted on the screenshot:

[image]